# How to have nautilus window divided into two or three columns (like mac) Miller Columns?

Tags: nautilus

I would like the nautilus windows look like a mac :

[image]

When you click on a folder (in the part 1 of screen), the content of this folder was display (in part 2 of screen)

It's very useful when you have many files.

It's possible to have this functionality in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a marlin fork:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

Related:

- [How to install pantheon-files on Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931097/how-to-install-pantheon-files-on-ubuntu-17-04)

Update 3: The instructions below are outdated, and Marlin may no longer be maintained? Thank you @kipbits for bringing this to my attention!

Update: So for gnome 3.

**Perhaps Marlin**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install marlin
sudo apt-get install marlin-plugin-*
```

What you are looking for is a Columns View capable window/file manager as seen [(here).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) Nautilus is still discussing whether to include Miller Columns.

For gnome2/nautilus themes:

Install and configure a new theme. [(like this)](http://www.howtoforge.com/mac4lin_make_linux_look_like_a_mac) Download [(mac4lin)](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=91113)

Comment: I was already instaled this theme. It is a Gnome2.x theme ( I use Gnome3/Unity) and it don't add the fonctionnality, it's "just" a icon pack

Comment: For a Columns View capable window manager try Dolphin for KDE4. Might be easier with Kubuntu.

Comment: After doing some searching it looks like Marlin is capable of [(Miller Columns)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) Column View.