# How to install pantheon-files on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, pantheon

I've tried to use this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
```

but it says "Unable to locate package pantheon-files"

```
grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
```

And

```
apt policy pantheon-files
N: Unable to locate package pantheon-files
```

Comment: what is the output of `apt policy pantheon-files`? add it to your question.

Comment: Also output of `grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is release for 17.04.
Only way is this:

edit the source list of elementary os ppa:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary-os-ubuntu-daily-zesty.list
```

after change "zesty" or name of version of ubuntu with "xenial" like as:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu xenial main
```

after:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

Comment: elementary os daily now provides packages for 17.10

Answer (score 2):

First add the repository(what you already did) with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

When adding a repository always execute

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

should do it

Comment: nope, it's still "unable to locate package pantheon-files" :(

Comment: not work in ubuntu 21.01