# How to install Pantheon Files (Elementary OS File Manager) in Ubuntu OS with ‘Open in Terminal’ in Context menu?

Tags: gnome-terminal, filemanager, konsole, context-menu, pantheon

**I've installed Pantheon File manager in Ubuntu OS. But ‘Open in Terminal’ is not available in Context menu. How to add it to Context menu?**

Comment: Please write the solution as an answer. Edit the question to something like "How to add open in terminal in Pantheon fules?"

Comment: This looks like an answer but you've written it as a question. Elementary is off-topic here (covered at https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) as it's not Ubuntu, nor [*flavor*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu.  If you want the Ubuntu question/answer to live on this site, please limit it to Ubuntu, and write a question, then please answer your own question

Comment: @guiverc In the beginning of the post, op explains how to install Pantheon files in Ubuntu. The post (once properly written as an question/answer) is on topic in this site.

Comment: I realize/saw that, but to me it's still written as two questions, one part belongs on this site (relating to Ubuntu), and the Elementary details (*off-topic here*) belong on https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/ where it is on-topic.  @ArchismanPanigrahi   (my 2c, but I'm not a *mod* here)

Comment: @AKB1794 For this question not to be removed from the site you need to remove the info about the off topic OS. Elementary OS is off topic on this site.

Comment: I'm talking how we can use use pantheon-files on Ubuntu with with "context menu" for "Open terminal Here". So, how is it off topic? It's defiantly on topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> N.B. install Install pantheon file manager on Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

> if you have problem installation watch [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173589/how-to-install-pantheon-files-on-ubuntu-18-04-3) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931097/how-to-install-pantheon-files-on-ubuntu-17-04).

Now,

- Add ‘Open in Terminal’ edit the file or create using any text editor vi, nano, gedit, kate etc. Here I'm using gedit.

  `sudo gedit /usr/share/contractor/openinterminal.contract`

and add following code for elementery OS.

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open in terminal
Icon=terminal
Description=Open in terminal
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=pantheon-terminal -d %U
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-terminal
```

of if you use `gnome-terminal` then this,

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open in terminal
Icon=terminal
Description=Open in terminal
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory %U
Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal
```

or, if you use `konsole` then use this,

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open in terminal
Icon=terminal
Description=Open in terminal
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=konsole --workdir %U
Gettext-Domain=konsole
```

Save the file. Logout and login or restart.

[Credit](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/add-open-in-terminal-to-pantheon-context-menu-in-elementary-os/)